# Java.util.EmptyStackException exception using stack

Tags: java, stack

Hi I am practicing Leetcode and is doing the Min Stack exercise.
I am experiencing a Java.util.EmptyStackException on my code which is weird because looking at other submissions their code is almost the same as mine.

I would like to understand why my code below is throwing a Java.util.EmptyStackException
runtime error while other code submissions dont.
The exception is on the "getMin()" method.

Java.util.EmptyStackException
at line 101, java.base.java.util.Stack.peek
at line 39, MinStack.getMin
at line 72, **Driver**,**helperSelectMethod**

```
//MyCodeBelow
    class MinStack {

    private Stack <Integer> stack;
    private Stack <Integer> stackMinVal;
    
    
    public MinStack() {
        stack = new Stack<>();
        stackMinVal = new Stack<>();
    }
    
    public void push(int val) {        
        
        if(stackMinVal.isEmpty() || stackMinVal.peek() >= val){            
            stackMinVal.push(val);
        }  
        
        stack.push(val);
        
    }
    
    public void pop() {   
          
        if(stackMinVal != null || stack.peek().equals(stackMinVal.peek())){
            stackMinVal.pop();
        }
        stack.pop();
       
    }
    
    
    public int top() {
        return stack.peek();
    }
    
    public int getMin() {        

        return stackMinVal.peek();  //<-- java.util.EmptyStackException
        
    }
}
```

Below is a sample of other submission that is similar to my solution but is not experiencing the Java Empty Stack Exception on "getMin()" method

```
    class MinStack {
    
    private Stack<Integer> mainStack;
    private Stack<Integer> minStack;

    public MinStack() {
        mainStack = new Stack<>();
        minStack = new Stack<>();
    }
    
    public void push(int x) {
        mainStack.push(x);
        if (minStack.isEmpty() || x <= minStack.peek()) {
            minStack.push(x);
        }
    }
    
    public void pop() {
        if(mainStack.peek().equals(minStack.peek())) minStack.pop();
        mainStack.pop();
    }
    
    public int top() {
        return mainStack.peek();
    }
    
    public int getMin() {
        return minStack.peek();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this check: `stackMinVal != null`? Since it's always true, the alternate clause of the `||` operator is never evaluated, thus `stackMinVal` is always popped as a result of the the `pop` call.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk my initial code does not have that validation.  But if I remove it the java util empty stack exception is thrown there.  After I added that validation it moved to the getMin method